# If VisualSVN is set to Nginx proxy_pass, it will be automatically redirected to the VisualSVN port

Tags: nginx, visualsvn-server

If VisualSVN is set to Nginx `proxy_pass`, it will be automatically redirected to the VisualSVN port.

If you try to move from A to A, you will go to B.

- A: `https://svn.abcde.com/svn/ABCDE/trunk/com.abcde.web`
- B: `https://svn.abcde.com**:9444**/svn/ABCDE/trunk/com.abcde.web/`

If you enter it like `https://svn.abcde.com/svn/ABCDE/trunk/com.abcde.web/`, it will move normally. It seems to be the problem of the last slash.

httpd 2.4 reverse_proxy is remembered as normal.

Thank you in advance for your help.

## nginx

```
server {
  listen            443 ssl http2 ;
  server_name       svn.abcde.com;

  include           /SSL.Cert.conf;

  location / {          
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9444;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

## VisualSVN (Initial setting)

```
Listen "9444" https

LoadModule licensing_visualsvn_module bin/mod_licensing_visualsvn.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module bin/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module bin/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_core_module bin/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module bin/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_user_module bin/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_visualsvn_module bin/mod_authz_visualsvn.so
LoadModule alias_module bin/mod_alias.so
LoadModule dir_module bin/mod_dir.so
LoadModule mime_module bin/mod_mime.so
LoadModule setenvif_module bin/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule rewrite_module bin/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule expires_module bin/mod_expires.so
LoadModule dav_module bin/mod_dav.so
LoadModule visualsvn_module bin/mod_visualsvn.so
LoadModule headers_module bin/mod_headers.so
LoadModule ssl_module bin/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule deflate_module bin/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule deflate_fh_module bin/mod_deflate_fh.so
LoadModule authn_visualsvn_svn_module bin/mod_authn_visualsvn_svn.so

Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
SVNCompressionLevel 1
DeflateCompressionLevel 1
DeflateAlterETag NoChange
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE_FH;DEFLATE

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/svn$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^SVN/
  RewriteRule ^(.*/svn)$ %0/ [R=301,L]
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  =GET  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  =HEAD
RewriteRule "^/favicon.ico$" "/!/assets/img/favicon.ico" [PT,NS]

<Location />
  AuthName "VisualSVN Server"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile "D:/VisualSVN Server/Repositories/htpasswd"

  Require valid-user
</Location>

SVNInMemoryCacheSize 131072

<Location "/svn/">
  DAV visualsvn

  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath "D:/VisualSVN Server/Repositories"
  SVNIndexXSLT "/!/assets/xsl/svnindex-ng.xsl?v=2"

  SVNPathAuthz short_circuit

  SVNCacheTextDeltas off
  SVNCacheFullTexts off
  SVNCacheRevProps off
  SVNCacheNodeProps on
  SVNBlockRead off

  SVNAllowBulkUpdates prefer

  AuthName "VisualSVN Server"
  AuthzVisualSVNMode Subversion
  AuthzVisualSVNSubversionReposRelativeAccessFile "VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini"
  AuthzVisualSVNSubversionGroupsFile "D:/VisualSVN Server/Repositories/groups.conf"

  ExpiresActive off
  Header always setifempty Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'"
</Location>

Alias /! WebUI
<Location /!>
  AuthzVisualSVNAuthoritative off
  SVNOverrideAll on
  DAV off
  ExpiresActive on
  Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none';form-action 'none';connect-src 'self'"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY

  <IfModule mime_module>
    AddCharset utf-8 .css
  </IfModule>
</Location>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I use VisualSVN behind a reverse proxy with IIS and I have the same problem. Will be attentive to any comments.